# Complexidade de algoritmo de dois laços

Tags: complexidade-de-algoritmo, ciência-da-computação

Qual seria a função de complexidade e o Big O do código abaixo?

```
int[] alg4(int[] arr1, int[] arr2) {
  int i = 0;
  int j = 0;
  int[] arr3 = new int[arr1.Length+arr2.Length];

  for (i = 0; i < arr1.Length; i++)
  arr3[j++] = arr1[i];

  for (i = 0; i < arr2.Length; i++)
  arr3[j++] = arr2[i];

  return arr3;
}
```

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos).

Answer (score 2):

A complexidade é linear, que costuma ser representada por O(n). E pode ser calculada com expressão que já está em código, o `n` da complexidade é justamente a soma dos tamanhos dos dois *arrays*. Todas vez que existe um laço simples assim, a complexidade é sempre linear, e no caso como tem dois laços é a soma deles. Seria diferente se eles estivessem aninhados.

Comment: Pode até representar como `o(|arr1| + |arr2|)`